# How to use chronology package to draw this timeline?

Tags: chronology

I want to use the [`chronology`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronology) package to draw a timeline from 2011 until 2016 where each year should be a major tick and between each major tick, there should be 3 minor ticks.

I tried to implement this like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[3]{2011}{2016}{3ex}{\textwidth}

\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

However, this ends up in a timeline like this:

[image: output]

How can I achieve the timeline I want?

Comment: Do you just need the timeline (I mean, would it be valid to produce the timeline *without* the chronology package) or are you planning to use other features from the `chronology` package?

Comment: I'm planning to add a couple of events and time ranges. So yes, I need the chronology package.

Comment: the phrase "where is year should be a major tick": do you mean "where each year should be a major tick"?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to change taht.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original `chronology` environment doesn't allow this. Below I defined a `markschronology` environment which behaves in a similar fashion to `chronology` (it has the same arguments and it was defined following the original definition) and allows you to specify a number of intermediate ticks; the number of intermediate ticks is controlled by `\Marks` with default value `0` (i.e., no intermediate ticks):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}

\def\Marks{0}

\makeatletter
\def\@marks{}
\newenvironment{markschronology}
  {%
    \@ifstar{\chronology@startrue\markschronology@i*}  {\chronology@starfalse\markschronology@i*}%
  }
  {%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \raisebox{2ex}{%
      \resizebox{\timelinewidth}{!}{\usebox{\timelinebox}}%
    }%
  }

\def\markschronology@i*{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\markschronology@ii*}{\markschronology@ii*[{5}]}%
}

\def\markschronology@ii*[#1]#2#3#4{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\markschronology@iii*[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}}{\markschronology@iii*[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}[{#4}]}%
}

\def\markschronology@iii*[#1]#2#3#4[#5]{%
  \newif\ifflipped%
  \ifchronology@star%
    \flippedtrue%
  \else%
    \flippedfalse%
  \fi%
  \setcounter{step}{#1}%
  \setcounter{yearstart}{#2}\setcounter{yearstop}{#3}%
  \setcounter{deltayears}{\theyearstop-\theyearstart}%
  \setlength{\unit}{#5/\thedeltayears}%
  \setlength{\timelinewidth}{#4}%
  \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstart}{\theyearstart+\thestep-mod(\theyearstart,\thestep)}%
  \pgfmathsetcounter{stepstop}{\theyearstop-mod(\theyearstop,\thestep)}%
  \addtocounter{step}{\thestepstart}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\timelinebox}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]%
    \draw [|->] (0,0) -- (\thedeltayears*\unit+\unit, 0);%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\thedeltayears}
    {
      \draw[xshift=\x*\unit] (0,-0.1\unit) -- (0,0.1\unit);%
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\@marks}{1+(1/(\Marks+1))}
    \foreach \x in {1,\@marks,...,\thedeltayears}
    {
      \draw[xshift=\x*\unit] (0,-0.05\unit) -- (0,0.05\unit);%
    }
    \addtocounter{deltayears}{1}%
    \foreach \x in {\thestepstart,\thestep,...,\thestepstop}
    {%
      \pgfmathsetlength\xstop{(\x-\theyearstart)*\unit}%
      \ifflipped%
        \node at (\xstop,0) [above=.2\unit] {\x};%
      \else%
        \node at (\xstop,0) [below=.2\unit] {\x};%
      \fi%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{markschronology}[1]{2010}{2016}{\textwidth}
\end{markschronology}\par\bigskip

\def\Marks{3}
\noindent\begin{markschronology}[1]{2010}{2016}{\textwidth}
\end{markschronology}\par\bigskip

\def\Marks{5}
\noindent\begin{markschronology}[1]{2010}{2016}{\textwidth}
\end{markschronology}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you write, whether the original package is able to do this or not(and thereby justifying your hard work:o)

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen done! :)

Comment: Sounds great. When I compile your code I get the following error: ! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@c ->\chronology@starfalse 
                                    \markschronology@i *
l.70 \noindent\begin{markschronology}[
                                      1]{2010}{2016}{\textwidth}
?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Are you using updated versions of the packages? If you compile just my example code exactly as it is, do you still get the same error message?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That's exactly what I did, I copied all your code and compiled it.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Then, please check that your packages are updated.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Sorry to bother you, but I am curioous; did the code finally work for you or are you still having problems?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I update all my packages again to be sure, but still the same error message. Could not yet figure it out.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException please add `\listfiles` to the exact same code I posted in my answer, process the document and upload elsewhere the `.log` file so I can have a look at it.

Comment: Hi, not only I have the same problem, but writing in the timeline (using the same approach as `chronology` does through `\event`) produces a visually bad output (grey circle + text too big). I wonder if you manage to solve at least the compiling the problem.

Comment: @Masiar perhaps you could open a fresh new question showing a little complete document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I was about to, but I thought it would have been closed redirecting here. In the meantime I modified myself the package and I'm trying to achieve something. If I can't get anywhere, I'll open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: What should I change if the step is 50 (more than 1)?