# Remove '-' and add BC in timeline

Tags: timeline

I'd like the timeline as shown, except the -ve year labels replaced with BC. I can't seem to find how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\begin{document}

\startchronology
[startyear=-800,stopyear=-14, arrow=false, height=0.2em, dateselevation=10pt]
\chronoevent{-753}{Rome's foundation}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315671/timelines-minus-years-and-the-year-zero could help

Comment: @alice19 Not so long ago, `@cfr` proposed a fantastic solution for an alternative using `Tikz` -- the so-called `chronos`, an alternative for `chronosys`. With that you can do `\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
 chronos={%
  start date={{-800}-01-01},
  end date={{-14}-01-01},
      step years=50,
only text,
timeline width=100mm,
timeline marks,
timeline mark eras,
timeline year={font=\scriptsize},
lines/.style={draw=none},
events/.append style={rotate=-45, anchor=west},
event distance=-2.5pt,
 }
 ]
 \chronosevent{{-753}}[text=gray]{Rome's Foundation}
 \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @samcarter apparently we both looked into the same reference ;)

Comment: @Raaja Well, it's a good reference :)

Comment: @samcarter yes indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\newcommand{\mychronodatestyle}[1]{

\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? int(abs(#1)):#1 }
\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? "BC":}
 ~\pgfmathresult
 }


 \catcode`\!=11
 \def\eventyear{\!chreventyear}
 \catcode`\!=12

 \newcommand{\myeventdatestyle}[1]{
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? int(abs(\eventyear)):"#1"}
\pgfmathresult
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? "BC":}
 ~\pgfmathresult
 }



\begin{document}


\startchronology
[startyear=-800,stopyear=-14, arrow=false, height=0.2em, dateselevation=10pt,
datesstyle=\mychronodatestyle
]
\chronoevent[datestyle=\myeventdatestyle ]
{12/-753}{Rome's foundation}

\chronoperiode[datesstyle=\mychronodatestyle,dateselevation=2pt]{-500}{-200}{important event}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @alice19 Pleased to know that your problem is solved!

Comment: I'm embarrassed to ask but is there any way to make this for a date range? For example, if something is dates to 750-740 BC?

Comment: @alice19 You should not be embarrassed at all.! It's a pleasure for me. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Now however if I have two dates that are rather close together they overlap each other. Shall I ask a new question about this?

Comment: @alice19 I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: thanks :) have done so