# Date label text overlapping in chronosys

Tags: timeline

I'm attempting (with huge help from Hafid Boukhoulda who helped [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472916/remove-and-add-bc-in-timeline)) to utilise chronosys to construct a number of timelines, mostly on BC date ranges. Most data has been fixed-points, so not a problem, but some are events dated only to date ranges. I come across a problem when date ranges are close together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\newcommand{\mychronodatestyle}[1]{

\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? int(abs(#1)):#1 }
\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? "BC":}
 ~\pgfmathresult
 }


 \catcode`\!=11
 \def\eventyear{\!chreventyear}
 \catcode`\!=12

 \newcommand{\myeventdatestyle}[1]{
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? int(abs(\eventyear)):"#1"}
\pgfmathresult
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? "BC":}
 ~\pgfmathresult
 }



\begin{document}


\startchronology
[startyear=-800,stopyear=-14, arrow=false, height=0.2em, dateselevation=10pt,
datesstyle=\mychronodatestyle
]
\chronoevent[datestyle=\myeventdatestyle ]
{12/-753}{Rome's foundation}

\chronoperiode[datesstyle=\mychronodatestyle,dateselevation=2pt]{-350}{-320}{important event}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image: Snippet showing problem]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your datestyle was inadequate for the narrow date band provided.  So I created an alternate (vertical) date style (named `\mychronovdatestyle`, note the `v`) for such narrowly spaced events.

I also added a number of `%` chars at line end, to suppress stray spaces from getting introduced into the labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\newcommand{\mychronodatestyle}[1]{%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? int(abs(#1)):#1 }%
\pgfmathresult%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? "BC":}%
 ~\pgfmathresult%
 }

\newcommand{\mychronovdatestyle}[1]{%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? int(abs(#1)):#1 }%
\edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? "BC":}%
 \kern-1.5pt\rotatebox[origin=left]{90}{--- \tmp~\pgfmathresult}%
 }

 \catcode`\!=11
 \def\eventyear{\!chreventyear}
 \catcode`\!=12

 \newcommand{\myeventdatestyle}[1]{%
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? int(abs(\eventyear)):"#1"}%
\pgfmathresult%
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? "BC":}%
 ~\pgfmathresult%
 }
\begin{document}
\startchronology
[startyear=-800,stopyear=-14, arrow=false, height=0.2em, dateselevation=10pt,
datesstyle=\mychronodatestyle
]
\chronoevent[datestyle=\myeventdatestyle ]
{12/-753}{Rome's foundation}

\chronoperiode[color=red,datesstyle=\mychronovdatestyle,dateselevation=-7pt]
  {-350}{-320}{important event}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP asks if the vertical dates could be placed below the line, at the expense of omitting the label.

I took no effort to make it pretty, but just minimized the modifications necessary from the above MWE:

1. removed "important event" text, leaving argument blank.
2. changed the `dateselevation` from `-7pt` to `-10pt`.
3. changed the `\rotatebox` angle from 90 to -90.
4. changed the label pre-kern from -1.5pt to 1.5pt.

The new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\newcommand{\mychronodatestyle}[1]{%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? int(abs(#1)):#1 }%
\pgfmathresult%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? "BC":}%
 ~\pgfmathresult%
 }

\newcommand{\mychronovdatestyle}[1]{%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? int(abs(#1)):#1 }%
\edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}%
\pgfmathparse{equal(sign(#1),-1)? "BC":}%
 \kern1.5pt\rotatebox[origin=left]{-90}{--- \tmp~\pgfmathresult}%
 }

 \catcode`\!=11
 \def\eventyear{\!chreventyear}
 \catcode`\!=12

 \newcommand{\myeventdatestyle}[1]{%
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? int(abs(\eventyear)):"#1"}%
\pgfmathresult%
 \pgfmathparse{equal(sign(\eventyear),-1)? "BC":}%
 ~\pgfmathresult%
 }
\begin{document}
\startchronology
[startyear=-800,stopyear=-14, arrow=false, height=0.2em, dateselevation=10pt,
datesstyle=\mychronodatestyle
]
\chronoevent[datestyle=\myeventdatestyle ]
{12/-753}{Rome's foundation}

\chronoperiode[color=red,datesstyle=\mychronovdatestyle,dateselevation=-10pt]
  {-350}{-320}{}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Perfect! Would it be possible to have the dash and date text at underneath though, to match the single-date points?

Comment: @alice19 That would be harder, but maybe it could be done...what about "important event" which would then interfere?

Comment: @StevenBSegletes Sorry, despite my mwe, that text is not needed for my purposes. It can be omitted.

Comment: @StevenBSegletes let me know if it isn't possible - either way i'll accept your answer in a bit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @alice19  Done!!