# Chronosys - Write events above the timeline

Tags: chronosys

So I have a timeline with events that are very close to eachother, to avoid them overlapping, I would like to write events under and above the timeline in alternance. It seems that by default, events are always written under the timeline... Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483039/date-label-text-overlapping-in-chronosys

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In case the linked question doesn't provide an answer to your one, please add a [minimal but complete example document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your question which makes it easier for others to help