# Package chronosys to build timeline

Tags: timeline, chronosys

The package chronosys provides a nice solution to build timeline, where events and periods are marked on a line. Here's an example from the user manual:

```
\startchronology
\chronoevent{476}{Event 1}
\chronoevent{1492}{Event 2}
\chronoevent{1969}{Event 3}
\stopchronology
```

The result is:

[image]

My question is the following. As we can see, all the events are placed below the line. How can I put, e.g., Event 2 above the line?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483039/date-label-text-overlapping-in-chronosys

Answer (score 6):

There are dozens of options in CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf

However it is not documented that some can be applied as a negative and markdepth is one of those.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\begin{document}
\startchronology
\chronoevent{476}{Event 1}
\chronoevent[markdepth=-23pt]{1492}{Event 2}
\chronoevent{1969}{Event 3}
\stopchronology
\end{document}
```