# Latex Chronology With Logarithmic Scale

Tags: chronology

I would like to use the `chronology` package to draw an axis in logarithmic scale with labels at specific points. Is there a way to modify the package to allow log scale?

Thanks.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
      \begin{chronology}[5]{300}{14000000}{\textwidth}
         \event{320}{A}
         \event{10520}{B}
         \event{13702520}{B}
      \end{chronology}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is probably "no". Here's a work-around:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{chronology}

\begin{document}
% some preparations
% 320 = 3.2 * 100
% 10520 = 1.052 E4
% 13702520 = 1.370252 E7
% 14000000 = 1.4 E7
%
% lg(3.2) = 0.505 => 2.505
% lg(1.052) = 0.022 => 4.022
% lg(1.37) = 0.137 = 7.137
%
\begin{figure}[t]
      \begin{chronology}[1]{1}{8}{\textwidth}
         \event{2.505}{A}
         \event{4.022}{B}
         \event{7.137}{C}
      \end{chronology}
      \caption{Events on a logarithmic time scale, spaning $100$ to $100E6$ years}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

**P.S.**: May be you prefer this one?

```
\event{2.505}{A - yr 320}
```

[image: some modification]