# How is this timeline figure created?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, timeline, chronology

does someone recognise the package that is used to make the figure below? Or, does someone know how to exactly create this? Some assistance would be appreciated - I am still unexperienced with tikz/chronology/etc. Ideally, I would have a dictionary/list as input for this figure. Different colours do not necessarily matter.

[image: Timeline (Fig 2. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.06435.pdf)]

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.06435.pdf (Fig. 2)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If your question is really how this was created, you should ask the authors of the related paper. This question would then be off-topic here. If your question is how to redraw this, you should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and show what you tried so far. There are surely some diagrams on this site or in the internet that at least can serve as a starting point for an MWE. The [Ti*k*Z manual](https://tikz.dev) contains some nice tutorials that can help you getting started.

Comment: Given the meta data of the image, which lists `cairo 1.17.4` as producer, I would guess some drawing program which uses cairo to export the image to pdf. I can't see any indication that this was produces with latex.

Comment: You can go to https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06435 to download the source (I had to add `.zip`) and see that it's simply `\includegraphics[width=2\columnwidth]{Figure/LLM_chart.pdf}` in the TeX.  I agree with samcarter that this doesn't seem to have been produced with TeX.  But like Jasper said, if you provide your attempt at doing this in TeX, we could help you complete the drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that I don't think I ought to answer do-it-for-mes.*

A [chronos](https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos) version:

[image: chronos version]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703431/
% https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos
\usepackage{chronos}

\begin{document}
\begin{chronos}
  [
    timeline={%
      dates=2019:{2024-01-01},
      timeline years=below,
      height=1pt,
      width=150mm,
      timeline year={text=black},
      timeline foreground=black,
    },
    colour scheme=blues,
    only text,
    every text tags={text=black,fill=##1!25,draw=black,font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
    event/tag+={tag anchor=west,anchor=south west},
    every connections={draw=black},
    /tikz/my label/.style={label={[font=\scriptsize\sffamily,text=black]left:\MakeTitlecase{#1}}},
  ]
  \chronosevent{name=new year,date=2019-01-01,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt,my label=jan}
    \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially new year)] in {martin luther king/,wintry storms/feb,dydd dewi sant/mar,april fools/apr,may day/may,longest day/jun,holidays/jul,sunshine/aug,back to school/sep,all hallows eve/oct,fireworks/nov,christmas/dec,hanukkah/}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,date=2019-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.north west,my label=\j}
  }
  \chronosevent{name=new year,date=2020-01-01,yshift=-15pt,xshift=2pt,my label=jan,anchor=north west,connection+={shorten <=12pt}}
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially new year)] in {martin luther king/,wintry storms/feb,dydd dewi sant/mar,april fools/apr,may day/may,longest day/jun,holidays/jul,sunshine/aug,back to school/sep,all hallows eve/oct,fireworks/nov,christmas/dec,hanukkah/}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,date=2020-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.south west,my label=\j,anchor=north west,connection+={shorten <=12pt}}
  }
\end{chronos}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

A corrected version of `chronos.sty` now allows `-` in names without issue. Thanks for reporting this bug.

To include citation commands in the text tags, we need to make use of `name content` as well as `name`. `name content` should be the kind of thing you can use as the name of a coordinate or node in Ti*k*Z, while `name content` can include any input valid in the content of a node.

For example,

```
  \chronosevent{name=another new year,date=2022-01-01,name content={Yet Another Year \cite{westfahl:space}},xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt,my label=jan}
```

If we want to use citation commands in a `\foreach` loop, we need to use an additional variable and alter the `\chronosevent` to use it. For instance,

```
  \foreach \i/\j/\k [remember=\i as \ilast (initially another new year)] in {martin-luther-king//{MLK, Jr.},wintry-storms/feb/Winter Blizzards,dydd dewi sant/mar/Dathlu!,april fools/apr/Hwyl!,may--day/may/{May Day \cite{padhye}},longest day/jun/{\Textcite{chiu}},holidays/jul/{\Autocite{jcg,nietzsche:historie}},sunshine/aug/Gwyliau,back to school/sep/Learning Ladder,all hallows eve/oct/Nos Galan Gaeaf,fireworks/nov/{Tân Gwyllt},christmas/dec/Nadolig,hanukkah//Festival of Light}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,name content={\k},date=2022-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.north west,my label=\j}
  }
```

This produces

[image: modified timeline using citation commands]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703431/
% https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos
\usepackage{chronos}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronos}
  [
    timeline={%
      dates=2019:{2024-01-01},
      timeline years=below,
      height=1pt,
      width=150mm,
      timeline year={text=black},
      timeline foreground=black,
    },
    colour scheme=blues,
    only text,
    every text tags={text=black,fill=##1!25,draw=black,font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
    event/tag+={tag anchor=west,anchor=south west},
    every connections={draw=black},
    /tikz/my label/.style={label={[font=\scriptsize\sffamily,text=black]left:\MakeTitlecase{#1}}},
  ]
  \chronosevent{name=another new year,date=2022-01-01,name content={Yet Another Year \cite{westfahl:space}},xshift=2pt,yshift=1pt,my label=jan}
  \foreach \i/\j/\k [remember=\i as \ilast (initially another new year)] in {martin-luther-king//{MLK, Jr.},wintry-storms/feb/Winter Blizzards,dydd dewi sant/mar/Dathlu!,april fools/apr/Hwyl!,may--day/may/{May Day \cite{padhye}},longest day/jun/{\Textcite{chiu}},holidays/jul/{\Autocite{jcg,nietzsche:historie}},sunshine/aug/Gwyliau,back to school/sep/Learning Ladder,all hallows eve/oct/Nos Galan Gaeaf,fireworks/nov/{Tân Gwyllt},christmas/dec/Nadolig,hanukkah//Festival of Light}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,name content={\k},date=2022-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.north west,my label=\j}
  }
  \chronosevent{name=new-year,date=2021-01-01,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt,my label=jan}
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially new-year)] in {martin-luther-king/,wintry-storms/feb,dydd dewi sant/mar,april fools/apr,may--day/may,longest day/jun,holidays/jul,sunshine/aug,back to school/sep,all hallows eve/oct,fireworks/nov,christmas/dec,hanukkah/}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,date=2021-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.north west,my label=\j}
  }
  \chronosevent{name=new year,date=2019-01-01,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt,my label=jan}
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially new year)] in {martin luther king/,wintry storms/feb,dydd dewi sant/mar,april fools/apr,may day/may,longest day/jun,holidays/jul,sunshine/aug,back to school/sep,all hallows eve/oct,fireworks/nov,christmas/dec,hanukkah/}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,date=2019-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.north west,my label=\j}
  }
  \chronosevent{name=new year,date=2020-01-01,yshift=-15pt,xshift=2pt,my label=jan,anchor=north west,connection+={shorten <=12pt}}
  \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially new year)] in {martin luther king/,wintry storms/feb,dydd dewi sant/mar,april fools/apr,may day/may,longest day/jun,holidays/jul,sunshine/aug,back to school/sep,all hallows eve/oct,fireworks/nov,christmas/dec,hanukkah/}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,date=2020-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.south west,my label=\j,anchor=north west,connection+={shorten <=12pt}}
  }
\end{chronos}
\end{document}
```

I've used Biblatex for the example, but this should work with standard BibTeX of LaTeX's builtin bibliography support, too. I used Biblatex because its more, rather than less, complex and supports a wider range of commands and characters.

Comment: Very nice package. Didn't find it at a glance: can you use a (true) logarithmic timescale to visualize very large periods of time (geology, universe etc.) ?

Comment: @MS-SPO No. It uses `pgfcalendar` for the calculations and I don't think that would cope with the dates involved. I'm assuming you wouldn't normally deal with those dates by turning them into Julian days, for example?

Comment: right. It would probably be more like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606061/245790

Comment: @MS-SPO Indeed. I liked that answer when I saw it before ;). Even dealing with smaller timescales, there's no point it calculating days if you're looking at twenty thousand years, say. I guess what might be possible would be to generalise the framework so different calculation/scaling methods could be plugged into a common framework for styling/placement, but I've not really given that any thought.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I am still facing some issues for my use case: whenever the name contains a "-", the list does not stack up properly anymore and instead pushes those items to the first year. Similarly, would it be possible to `\cite{...}` within the bubbles, e.g. "dash-text-or-other-symbols+ [1]"? I tried surrounding it with brackets amongst other things, but I cannot get these two changes working unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @SWE (1) For `\cite`: `name content={... \cite{} ...}` and `name=simplething`.  If you do this, `chronos` won't mangle `name content` because it won't try to use it in constructing node and coordinate names. If you put that stuff in `name`, `chronos` tries to make it into something acceptable as a node/coordinate name by stripping out problematic stuff. You can also use `as is`, but then it will try to use the unmodified version in names, which won't work. (2) I wouldn't expect there to be a problem with `-` in names. Do you have an example? That sounds like something I should try to fix.

Comment: @SWE Never mind about the example. I see the problem. The `-` issue is definitely a bug.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the reply, the `name content={<something> \cite{}}` works great within the bubble itself. However, it also seems to cause similar behaviour like the `-`, it moves the rest of the stack (above it) completely the the start/left. EDIT: Just saw a new commit in your repository! I will retry with this newer version.

Comment: @SWE I've uploaded a fix for the `-` in names to codeberg (so you don't need `name content`). I'll see if I can reproduce the `\cite` issue with `name content`.

Comment: Here is an example to reproduce the `\cite`:
`\chronosevent{name content={test-1 \cite{test-1}},date=2019-01-01,yshift=1pt,xshift=2pt,my label=jan}
    \foreach \i/\j [remember=\i as \ilast (initially test-1)] in {{test-2 \cite{test-2}}/,test3/feb,test+4/dec,TEST5/}
  {
    \chronosevent{name/.expand once=\i,date=2019-01-01,at=text tag \ilast.north west,my label=\j}
  }`

Comment: @SWE Please see edit for an example of how to set this up. You need to use `name` as well as `name content` and you need a third variable in the loop for these cases. Thanks for reporting the `-` bug and getting me to test with citations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starting point you could use.

Basic ideas:

- draw a thicker line as timeline
- place years
- for every year: place nodes with a fill color for the items
- for every year: put a month, and draw a vertical line

For simplicity styles are mentioned in the beginning. Any change here affects the whole graphics:

- make the right side (east) anchor at the coordinate for the `mnth`, so it's left
- define a style `lbl` for the boxes in the light color; anchor west (i.e. opposite)
- reuse and redefine this style for the darker color as `dbl`

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ 
    mnth/.style={anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    lbl/.style={draw,
                fill=blue!25!white!30,
                anchor=west, xshift=1mm,
                font={\footnotesize},
                },
    dbl/.style={lbl,fill=teal!40},
 ]
```

The timeline is put more ore less automatically:

- variable `\yr` runs through the set of years
- the 1st, 2nd etc. of these is counted via `\i`
- `\i` helps to calculate the coordinate of the node, which outputs `\yr`

```
    % ~~~ timeline ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- +(25,0); 
    \foreach \yr [count=\i] in {2019,2020,...,2024}
        \node at (5*\i - 5, -.3) {\yr};
```

For each year perform these actions manually:

- draw a vertical line, here using a starting point and a delta upwards
- put as many nodes as needed with the `mnth` style for the months
- put as many nodes as needed with the `lbl` or `dbl` style for the items
- using increments of 0.5cm seem to work fine here

```
    % ~~~ 2019 ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,0) -- +(0,.3);
    \node[mnth] at (0, .3) {Oct};
    \node[lbl]  at (0, .3) {T5};
```

Repeat, until you're done.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ 
    mnth/.style={anchor=east,xshift=-1mm},
    lbl/.style={draw,
                fill=blue!25!white!30,
                anchor=west, xshift=1mm,
                font={\footnotesize},
                },
    dbl/.style={lbl,fill=teal!40},
 ]
 
    % ~~~ timeline ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- +(25,0); 
    \foreach \yr [count=\i] in {2019,2020,...,2024}
        \node at (5*\i - 5, -.3) {\yr};
    
    % ~~~ 2019 ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,0) -- +(0,.3);
    \node[mnth] at (0, .3) {Oct};
    \node[lbl]  at (0, .3) {T5};
    
    % ~~~ 2020 ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (5,-.6) -- +(0,.9);
    \node[mnth] at (5, .3) {Oct};
    \node[lbl]  at (5, .3) {mT5};
    \node[mnth] at (5, -.8) {May};
    \node[lbl]  at (5, -.8) {GPT-3};
    

    % ~~~ 2022 ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (15,-4) -- +(0,8);
    \node[mnth] at (15, .3) {Mar};
    \node[mnth] at (15, .8) {Apr};
    \node[dbl]  at (15, 1.3) {Tk-Instr};
    \node[lbl]  at (15, .8) {GPT-NeoX-20B};
    \node[lbl]  at (15, .3) {CodeGen};
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```