# Chronosys package

Tags: timeline, chronosys

I have been using chronosys for a few days now, and some problems have arisen. I have modified the file `chronosyschr.tex` to delete the reference to a year 0 that does not exist

```
\!chrdefaultstartyear chrdefaultstartyear{1}!chrdefaultstopyear chrdefaultstopyear chrdefaultwidth chrdefaultwidth chrdefaultwidth{\the\textwidth}%.
```

So, if you want a timeline with the BEC and EC centuries, the year 0 always appears :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}
     \begin{chronology}[align=left, startyear=-400, stopyear=500, height=1cm, startdate=false, stopdate=false,arrowheight=0.75cm,arrowwidth=0.75cm]
     \chronograduation[periode][dateselevation=0pt]{100}
     \end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Two another questions:

- How to make a timeline with important values (billions of years)?
- How to draw a fine line around each period or a block of periods?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Honestly? The answer is to use something other than `chronosys`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297660/ and the question to which it is an answer for details.

Comment: But billions of years would need quite different handling than any current approach, as far as I'm aware, because TeX can't deal with numbers that big when it comes to the calculations.

Comment: Thank a lot, cfr. Tikz: of course! I use it, but strangely enough I hadn't thought of it for timelines, despite the limits you indicate. I have to scale down my chronological ambitions…

Comment: I have an interest ;): https://codeberg.org/cfr/chronos.

Comment: I knew it! The hidden lobbyist had no choice but to unmask himself. My trap worked!

Comment: 'Hidden lobbyist'? Incidentally, `chronos` defaults to no year zero (but you can have one if you like).

Comment: I've just had a look at the Chronos documentation. Well, it's much better than Chronosys, more complete and more configurable.
OK: I'm adopting it!

Comment: It's also nowhere near as stable or well-tested. Actually, if you are going to try it, let me upload the current version as I hopefully fixed a spacing bug over the last couple of days. (Of course, all packages start out untested ....)

Comment: [As regards the payment of the bribe into my account in the Bahamas, we're doing as we agreed, aren't we?]

Comment: OK: I'm waiting for the debugged version

Comment: Done. (Second attempt - I'm not very good with `git` as the subversion numbers in some of my commit messages probably indicate.) Please report bugs on codeberg (or comment here). I expect there are bugs in both the code and the documentation. Parts of the code are from answers on SE, but the documentation is entirely new.